# Cassandra lack of scallability

Tags: cassandra, scalability

I have got a problem with scalability Cassandra database. In spite of increase the number of nodes from 2 to 8, performance of database doesn't grow.

```
Cassandra Version: 3.7
Cassandra Hardware x8: 1vCPU 2.5 Ghz, 900 MB RAM, SSD DISK 20GB, 10 Gbps LAN
Benchmark Hardware x1: 16vCPU 2.5 GHz, 8 GB RAM, SSD DISK 5GB, 10 Gbps LAN
```

Default settings were changed in cassandra.yaml:

```
cluster_name: 'tst'
seeds: "192.168.0.101,192.168.0.102,...108"
listen_address: 192.168.0.xxx
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
rpc_address: 192.168.0.xxx
concurrent_reads: 8
concurrent_writes: 8
concurrent_counter_writes: 8
```

Keyspace:

```
create keyspace tst WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : '2' };
```

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE shares (
    c1 int PRIMARY KEY,
    c2 varchar,
    c3 int,
    c4 int,
    c5 int,
    c6 varchar,
    c7 int
);
```

Examplary query used in tests:

```
INSERT INTO shares (c1, c1, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7) VALUES (%s, '%s', %s, %s, %s, '%s', %s)
```

For connect with base I will use https://github.com/datastax/java-driver. In multi-threads I use one of cluster object and one of session object according to the instructions. Connecting:

```
PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
poolingOptions.setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 5, 300);
poolingOptions.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 10);
poolingOptions.setPoolTimeoutMillis(5000);
QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);

Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
builder.withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions);
builder.withQueryOptions(queryOptions);
builder.withLoadBalancingPolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy());
this.setPoints(builder); // here all of the nodes are added
Cluster cluster = builder.build()
```

Code of query:

```
public ResultSet execute(String query) {
ResultSet result = this.session.execute(query);
return result;
}
```

During test work, using of memory on all of the nodes is 80%, and CPU 100%. I am surprised by using connections in monitor (is too low):

```
[2016-09-10 09:39:51.537] /192.168.0.102:9042 connections=10, current load=62, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:39:51.556] /192.168.0.103:9042 connections=10, current load=106, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:39:51.556] /192.168.0.104:9042 connections=10, current load=104, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:39:51.556] /192.168.0.101:9042 connections=10, current load=196, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:39:56.467] /192.168.0.102:9042 connections=10, current load=109, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:39:56.467] /192.168.0.103:9042 connections=10, current load=107, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:39:56.467] /192.168.0.104:9042 connections=10, current load=115, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:39:56.468] /192.168.0.101:9042 connections=10, current load=169, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:40:01.468] /192.168.0.102:9042 connections=10, current load=113, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:40:01.468] /192.168.0.103:9042 connections=10, current load=84, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:40:01.468] /192.168.0.104:9042 connections=10, current load=92, max load=10240
[2016-09-10 09:40:01.469] /192.168.0.101:9042 connections=10, current load=205, max load=10240
```

Code of the monitor: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.0/manual/pooling#monitoring-and-tuning-the-pool

I am trying to test scalability of few NoSQL databases. In case of Redis base it was linear scalability, here she is not at all and I don't know why. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What kinds of values do you have for your partition key? How well is the data being distributed? Cassandra distributes data by calculating a hash on the primary key. If all of your data has a small number of PK values, then it doesn't matter how many servers you use.

Answer (score 3):

1GB RAM on each machine is a very low target. This could be causing too much GC pressure. Check your log to see the GC activity and try to understand if this 100% CPU cap is due to JVM GC'ing all the time.

Another quirk: how many threads are you running on each machine? If you are trying to scale with this code (your code):

> Code of query:
>
> ```
> public ResultSet execute(String query) {
> ResultSet result = this.session.execute(query);
> return result;
> }
> ```

then you won't go very far. Synchronous queries are hopelessly slow. Even if you try to use more threads then 1GB of RAM could be (I already know it is...) too low... You should probably write async queries, for both  resource consumption and scalability.

Comment: Thanks! I use 1000 Threads in Benchmark. If I use asynchronously connection how i will check value of querys in part of time?

Comment: 1000 Threads are probably too many...Stick with 2x vCPU threads (so 32 threads in your case) and go the async route.You'll increase them later.Usually you collect a list of `ResultSetFuture` futures objects.When you collect **your** maximum number of inflight queries (make them 1000 initially) you wait for all of them to finish so you apply some backpressure and don't put your cluster under stress.You can also register callbacks to futures in case you prefer that style.See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries as an example.